# Jquery - sort DIV's by innerHTML of children

Tags: jquery, sorting, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got html that looks something like this:

```
<div id="sortThis">
<div id="1">Price:<span class="price">20</span><span class="style">blue</span></div>
<div id="2">Price:<span class="price">23</span><span class="style">red</span></div>
<div id="3">Price:<span class="price">10</span><span class="style">red</span></div>
<div id="4">Price:<span class="price">29</span><span class="style">green</span></div>
<div id="5">Price:<span class="price">35</span><span class="style">blue</span></div>
</div>
```

And I want to be able to sort by .price or by .style

I suspect that this post partially answers my question: [Sort Divs in Jquery Based on Attribute 'data-sort'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133723/sort-divs-in-jquery-based-on-attribute-data-sort)

And this plugin comes close to doing what I need (since it can handle child attributes) but it does not seem to go as far as children's innerHTML: http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

Any help will be appreciated by this noob.

Comment: you cant assign same ids in html. id's should be different

Comment: that's a little embarrassing - the DIV's now have unique id's

Comment: Never too late too clarify: Tinysort can sort by child innerHTML: http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/#subselection

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To do this sort directly using the child values and without a plugin, you could use something like:

```
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
    var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
        var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
        var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();
        return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    parent.append(items);
}
```

Sorting by price can then be done as such:

```
sortUsingNestedText($('#sortThis'), "div", "span.price");
```

The function is parametrised so that it can be easily reused with other divs and different sort keys.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tc5dc/

---

#### Using the tinysort plugin

Alternatively, if you can benefit from the features provided by the [tinysort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) plugin (mentioned in question), you could dynamically augment your divs to suit the plugin.

Check out this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6guj9/

In the example, we first add the `price` and `style` values as data attributes of the holding div:

```
var sortThis = $('#sortThis').children("div");
sortThis.each(function() {
    var p = $(this);
    p.attr("data-price", p.find("span.price").text());
    p.attr("data-style", p.find("span.style").text());
});
```

We're then free to use tinysort to sort on the relevant attributes. Sorting by price would be simply:

```
$("#sortThis>div").tsort({attr:"data-price"});
```

Changing the sort order and keys can be done by simply passing in different config objects. The linked demo shows one way to do this, but you can probably come up with a better scheme to suit your needs.

Comment: Excellent - this works nicely and I'm going to implement a version of this with the plugin. Much appreciated!

Comment: this code block `$("#sortThis>div").tsort({attr:"data-price"});` = Awesome

Comment: I was looking for jquery sorting, and you gave me the whole solution. Thx for saving time. :)

Comment: @ShawnChin http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/scripts/jquery.tinysort.js is no more exists and throwing 404 Error, and hence, the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6guj9/ is no longer working. Please update your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! #yearslost

Comment: If anyone else can't figure out why the results may be screwy. It could be because of upper/lower. Change these two lines: var vA = $(keySelector, a).text().toLowerCase();
            var vB = $(keySelector, b).text().toLowerCase();

Answer (score 10):

You can sort with jquery by doing

```
var mylist = $('ul');
var listitems = mylist.children("li");
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
   var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
   return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
})
$(mylist).append(listitems);
```

---

It automaticly sort by price if you do

```
var mylist = $('#sortThis');
var listitems = mylist.children("div");
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
   var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
    console.log((compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0);
   return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
})
$(mylist).append(listitems);
```

Ill see if i cant scratch something out with an if :)

---

Got something like:

```
if(sortorder === 'price') {

    var mylist = $('#sortThis');
    var listitems = mylist.children("div");
    listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
       var compA = $(a).children('.price').text().toUpperCase();
       var compB = $(b).children('.price').text().toUpperCase();
       return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
    })
    $(mylist).append(listitems);

} else if (sortorder === 'style') {

    var mylist = $('#sortThis');
    var listitems = mylist.children("div");
    listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
       var compA = $(a).children('.style').text().toUpperCase();
       var compB = $(b).children('.style').text().toUpperCase();
       return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
    })
    $(mylist).append(listitems);

}
```

Comment: Nice work! I made a small change and it works nicely: changed '=' to '==' in the IF statements.

Comment: Nice! I'm using it with JQM ListView. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Use my jquery plugin SortContent :

```
$('#sortThis').sortContent({asc:true});
```

You can use helper to sort according to the suitable conten that you want.

```
$('#sortThis').sortContent({asc:true,helper:function(e){return $(e).find('.price').html()}})
```

if you want to reverse order ,set `false` to `asc` option

Another note, you can select directly children of div instead of parent: It is the same :

```
$('#sortThis>div').sortContent({asc:true,helper:function(e){return $(e).find('.price').html()}})
```

DEMO :

http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/ytmry/

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the marked answer does not sort correctly, I tested it using numbers from 1 - 100 and it misinterpreted anything under 10. The reason being it works on a text value and the ASCII code instead of the actual numeric value.

Here I have converted the text values to Integers using parseInt() before sorting.

```
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
    var vA = parseInt($(keySelector, a).text());
    var vB = parseInt($(keySelector, b).text());
    return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
});
parent.append(items);
}
```

Then we call it the same

```
sortUsingNestedText($('#sortThis'), "div", "span.price");
```

Answer (score 0):

this was work for me.
This bellow code short the div in low to high base on the price text.

```
        var gridItems = $("#sortThis").children("div");

        gridItems.sort(function(a, b) {
            return $('.price',a).text() - $('.price',b).text();
        });

        $("#sortThis").append(gridItems);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it