# sort nested div tags in jquery: not desired result

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, xslt, nested

I have this code in my XSLT file:

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="kala.html">    
        <img alt="">                                    
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="/product/image"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </img>

        <div class="colors">
            <span class="color">colors</span>
            <span>        
                <xsl:value-of select="/product/color"/>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="ratings">
            <span class="rating">grades</span>
            <span class="grade">
                <xsl:value-of select="/product/rate"/>
            </span>
        </div>

        <h4>
            <xsl:value-of select="/product/title"/>
        </h4>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="/product/price"/>
        </p>
    </a>
</div>
```

There are some `div.item` in `div#serachResult`, now I want to sort these `div.item` by using the function from this post: [Jquery - sort DIV's by innerHTML of children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831712/jquery-sort-divs-by-innerhtml-of-children)

```
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
    var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
        var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
        var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();
        return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    parent.append(items);
}
```

When I try this:

```
sortUsingNestedText($('#searchResult'), "div.item", "span.grade");
```

The desired result is not obtained and the `div.item` are sorted randomly. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I solved my problem with add `parseFloat` in `sortUsingNestedText` function:

```
var vA = parseFloat($(keySelector, a).text());
var vB = parseFloat($(keySelector, b).text());
```