# Sorting divs by number inside div tag and jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting, numbers

I'm trying to sort a list of divs with jQuery. Essentially the list might look like this:

```
<div class="contest_entry"><img src="image.png" /><span class="votes">14</span></div>
<div class="contest_entry"><img src="image.png" /><span class="votes">8</span></div>
<div class="contest_entry"><img src="image.png" /><span class="votes">2</span></div>
<div class="contest_entry"><img src="image.png" /><span class="votes">2</span></div>
<div class="contest_entry"><img src="image.png" /><span class="votes">2</span></div>
<div class="contest_entry"><img src="image.png" /><span class="votes">21</span></div>
```

I'm trying to use some jQuery to automatically sort the divs by highest number to lowest. How could I go about this? Thanks for any direction! Guess I should add that the sort should happen on pageload. :)

Comment: Your question is related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433691/sorting-list-of-elements-in-jquery/8434126#8434126

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wrote a [small plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/XASZA/) just for this purpose. Feel free to steal. 
Basically you select elements, sort them, and reappend in the new order.

==============================================================================

Per Jason's request including code here

```
$(".contest_entry").orderBy(function() {return +$(this).text();}).appendTo("#parent_div");
```

`#parent_div` is a container for the `.contest_entry`s.

The `+` is just a sneaky way to convert value to number to force number compare rather than string compare (unless that is what you want).

`orderBy()` is a sorting plugin that I wrote. I expanded on it quiet a bit since then, but here is the simple version:

```
jQuery.fn.orderBy = function(keySelector)
{
    return this.sort(function(a,b)
    {
        a = keySelector.apply(a);
        b = keySelector.apply(b);
        if (a > b)
            return 1;
        if (a < b)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    });
};
```

Comment: +1 nicely done @liho1eye.  You should include the code in the answer, though, in case the link stops working and for easier reference.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){ 
    var sortedList = $('.contest_entry').toArray().sort(function(lhs, rhs){ 
        return parseInt($(rhs).children("span.votes").text(),10) - parseInt($(lhs).children("span.votes").text(),10); 
    });
    //the variable 'sortedList' holds the divs ordered. All you need to do is place them in the DOM.
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCvUa/

Comment: FYI: jQuery object steals its sort method directly from array, so there is no need to convert it back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing along these lines should work:

```
var list = [];

function sortDivs(a,b)
{
    return parseInt(a.text(), 10) - parseInt(b.text(), 10);
}

$('contest_entry').each(function () {
    list.push(this);
    $(this).detach();
})

list.sort(sortDivs)

for (var x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
    $('#parent_el').append(list[x]);//where parent_el is the place you want to reinsert the divs in the DOM
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jVotes = $('div.contest_entry span.votes'), vals = [];
jVotes.each(function() {
    var numVotes = $(this).html(); // may also be able to use .text()
    vals.push(numVotes);
    $(this).data('num-votes', numVotes);
});
vals.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
});
var jParent = $('selector for parent container');
for (var i = 0; i < jVotes.length; i++) {
    jParent.append(jParent.find('[data-num-votes=' + vals[i] + ']'));
}
```