# Sorting divs in two groups

Tags: jquery, sorting

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847712/sort-divs-bases-on-elements-data-attribute), but I have another issue which I need some help with.
I would like to be able to group my divs into two groups - both sorted. The sorting already works, but how do I seperate my dovs up into two groups? The container divs in group 2 contains an element with class="anotherGroup".

the markup is this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="terminal" data-price="195">
      <h3>195</h3>
  </div>
  195 - I should come in 2nd in group 1 which is displayed first.
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="terminal" data-price="220">
      <h3>220</h3>
  </div>
  220 - I should come in 3rd in group 1 which is displayed first.
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="terminal" data-price="740">
      <h3>740</h3>
  </div>
  740 - I should come in 2nd in group 2 which is displayed last.
  <div class="anotherGroup">Group 2</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="terminal" data-price="140">
      <h3>140</h3>
  </div>
  140 - I should come in 1st in group 2 which is displayed last.
  <div class="anotherGroup">Group 2</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="terminal" data-price="130">
      <h3>130</h3>
  </div>
  130 - I should come in 1st in group 1 which is displayed first.
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('.terminal').sort(function (a, b) {
  return $(a).data('price') - $(b).data('price');
}).map(function () {
  return $(this).closest('.container');
}).each(function (_, container) {
  $(container).parent().append(container);
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6TavH/2/).

The final result should be:

```
130
195
220
140
740
```

Where 140 and 740 belong in a group of their own because they contain an element with the classname "anotherGroup".
Hope this makes sense. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that you have only two groups. [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6TavH/6/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
var _count = 0;
$('.terminal').sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data('price') - $(b).data('price');
}).map(function () {
    return $(this).closest('.container');
}).each(paint);

function paint(_, container) {
    if ($(container).children('.anotherGroup')[0]) {
        $(container).parent().append(container);
    } else {
        var next = paint.next;
        if (next) {
            $(container).insertAfter(next);
        } else {
            $(container).parent().prepend(container);
        }
        paint.next = container;
    }
};
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6TavH/5/)**

Comment: For clear understanding, I added comments.. [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6TavH/6/).

Comment: That's pretty neat. Works great. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamicaly add another `data-` with the group :

```
// attr() required for dynamic data-xxx
$('.terminal').attr('data-group', 'Group 1'); 
$('.anotherGroup').each(function(el) {
    $(this).prev('.terminal').attr('data-group', $(this).html());
});
// Result : <div class="terminal" data-price="140" data-group="Group 2">
```

And use a concatenation of `data-group` and `data-price` to compare your elements :

```
$('.terminal').sort(function (a, b) {
    var atxt = $(a).data('group')+$(a).data('price');
    var btxt = $(b).data('group')+$(b).data('price');
    return atxt.toLowerCase().localeCompare(btxt.toLowerCase());
}).map(function () {
    return $(this).closest('.container');
}).each(function (_, container) {
    $(container).parent().append(container);
});
```

[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6TavH/4/)

Note : this will work for any group if you keep an alphabetical order ("Group 2", "Group 3"...)

Comment: This solution might come in handy as well. Thanks.