# Display array elements in html page as they are being entered

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

```
var contacts =[];

function getInfo() {
    var firstName = prompt("Enter first name");
    var lastName = prompt("Enter last name");
    var emailId = prompt("Enter Email ID");
    var phoneNo = prompt("Enter Phone number");
    var fname, lname, email, phone;
    var person ={
        fname : firstName,
        lname : lastName,
        email : emailId,
        phone : phoneNo
    }
    contacts.push(person);  




for(i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += contacts[i].fname+" "+contacts[i].lname;
}
}
```

> I want to display only the new array elements. In the above code, every time a new element enters the array all elements are displayed. How can I avoid repetition? I think using the DOM is an option. I'm stuck trying to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working snippet of what you asked. you just have to take the last pushed object from the array and display the names.

Also your `var fname, lname, email, phone` is not required, You can set the object properties on the fly.

```js
var contacts =[];

function getInfo() {
    var firstName = prompt("Enter first name");
    var lastName = prompt("Enter last name");
    var emailId = prompt("Enter Email ID");
    var phoneNo = prompt("Enter Phone number");
   // var fname, lname, email, phone; //also this is not required. you can set dynamic property names in a object.
    var person ={
        fname : firstName,
        lname : lastName,
        email : emailId,
        phone : phoneNo
    };
    contacts.push(person);  

    var currPerson = contacts[contacts.length-1]; //take the last pushed object from the array
    
    var lastNameFirstChar = currPerson.lname.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  
    if(!document.getElementById(lastNameFirstChar + "_holder")){      
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "<div  id='"+lastNameFirstChar+"_holder' class='holder'><span class='charValue'>"+lastNameFirstChar+"</span></br></div>";
    
  }
   document.getElementById(lastNameFirstChar + "_holder").innerHTML += currPerson.fname+" "+currPerson.lname + "<br/>";
 

}
```

```html
<button onclick="getInfo()">Get Person Info</button>
<p>----------------------------</p>
<div id="mydiv">

</div>
```

**EDIT:** Since you said you can use Jquery I have updated the solution with Jquery.

Comment: Cool. This is what I want exactly!

Comment: By the way, I also need to track of fname,lname,phone and email. When I click on the name, then the contact info should appear on the right side in the same page!

Comment: http://imgur.com/ZOXl5Sz   When I click on name, his/her details should appear on the right side in the same page

Comment: @Droidr that can be done, I will update my answer in few minutes.

Comment: I have already done it. But I am struck with displaying Contact list alphabetically separated as shown in the picture.

Comment: I don't see any contact in the picture, Guess you gave me the wrong link

Comment: This picture gives better idea http://i.stack.imgur.com/gB73T.png  . As of now I'm able to display the contact information on right side ( Using onClick( ) ) . But not separated the contact list by alphabetical order.

Comment: `not separated the contact list by alphabetical order` what do you mean?? Can you show whats your desired behaviour and current behaviour. I can help out

Comment: In current behavior I am not able to separate the names by first character of last name( As shown http://i.stack.imgur.com/gB73T.png )  As of now I can print them in the order as they are entered and display( Using onClick) the respective contact information ( full name , email, phone ) on right side.

Comment: ok, So you want to do as seen in the image? Then for every entry of the person you need to check his last name first character. You should first have a div with a attribute to say which Character it holds, An then check the last name first character and push to the divs accordingly. If the div is not there then you must create it dynamically.

Comment: Having div for each character sounds naive. In least possible case I will try that. How do I do that dynamically?

Comment: You can build the div dynamically too, when you don't find one.

Comment: I think you have to look the current code which is causing more difficulty to do this . How can I share it personally with you ?

Comment: I updated my code to do what you wanted, Have a check.. you can see all the names with the same last name first character goes under the same section

Comment: @Droidr again updated to fix few bugs, Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105436/discussion-between-droidr-and-reddy).

Comment: Is there a way to sort the <div> with this  approach?

Comment: I find it hard with current approach :D

Comment: actually its not, would you like to try it if I share some details?

Comment: Okay sure. Thanks for the help and I'll get back to you if I've questions :)

Comment: So here is what you can do.. While setting the Char to the div also set a data attribute to set the number to it, number must be the position, So something like `data-div-pos=0` for the char A, for this you can check online solution to get a Number for char and set it, Now you will have div's with numbers on it. You can now sort it. Here is a similar link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847712/sort-divs-bases-on-elements-data-attribute .Let me know if you have issues. All the best :) I want you to do this

Comment: In my case <div> are dynamic. Is it gonna work  if div are dynamic ? He's using document.ready , which isn't quite suitable in my case I think. Because I've to get the existing div to be sorted.

Comment: The above jsfiddle in my comment is exactly what you need. Did you look at it?

Comment: No but he is sorting on click of the button, you just need to sort while adding a new person into the DOM. just a function call bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105571/discussion-between-droidr-and-reddy).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, adding only the `last element` of `array` to `innerHTML`

```
var contacts =[];

function getInfo() {
    var firstName = prompt("Enter first name");
    var lastName = prompt("Enter last name");
    var emailId = prompt("Enter Email ID");
    var phoneNo = prompt("Enter Phone number");
    var fname, lname, email, phone;
    var person ={
        fname : firstName,
        lname : lastName,
        email : emailId,
        phone : phoneNo
    };
    contacts.push(person);  


    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += contacts[contacts.length-1].fname+" "+contacts[contacts.length-1].lname;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you add all the elements you have to empty your div.

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

just change:

```
if(contacts.length!=0){
   document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += contacts[contacts.length-1].fname+" "+contacts[contacts.length-1].lname;
}
```

The if check is for the start when length of array is zero