# Sort child div based on data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to sort children div based on data attributes

The html code below is being generated by a CM and the data can be retrieved in any random order.

the html code is

```
<section class="box explore">
<div id="ProductContainer"  class="row">
        <div id="1232132" data-name="B" data-category="Category_A" class="explore-cell">
         <h>B</h>
         <p>Category_A</p>
        </div>
    <div id="123" data-name="A" data-category="Category_A" class="explore-cell">
        <h>A</h>
        <p>Category_A</p>
    </div>
    <div id="1232152351" data-name="C" data-category="Category_A" class="explore-cell">
        <h>C</h>
        <p>Category_A</p>
    </div>
    <div id="12342341" data-name="E" data-category="Category_B" class="explore-cell">
        <h>E</h>
        <p>Category_B</p>
    </div>
    <div id="1325321" data-name="D" data-category="Category_B" class="explore-cell">
        <h>D</h>
        <p>Category_B</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

java

```
$('div').sort(function (a, b) {

  var contentA = $(a).attr('data-name');
  var contentB = $(b).attr('data-name');
  return (contentA < contentB) ? -1 : (contentA > contentB) ? 1 : 0;
```

})

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w8gkshue/

if someone can point me in the right direct on how to best sort either by Product Name or Category.

Updated hope this gives better explination

Comment: Are you trying to re-position the dom elements based on your sorting?

Comment: the divs generate a grid view of rows and cells, with the cells being out of order.  I was trying to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133723/sort-divs-in-jquery-based-on-attribute-data-sort as a starting point but did not work with strings

Answer (score 1):

You can use .sort method like this

```
var $wrapper = $('#ProductContainer');

$wrapper.find('.explore-cell').sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.getAttribute('data-name') > b.getAttribute('data-name');
})
.appendTo( $wrapper );
```

But I don't sure about the cross browsing support

Comment: would would be the best mtehod to attech to the div id rather then class there are multiple row classes

Comment: weird I will play around I can't get it to work local but that is a good start thanks brother

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I missed the jQuery tag... leaving the answer still.

```js
var productCt = document.getElementById('ProductContainer'),
    reInsertProductCt = tempRemove(productCt);


[].slice.call(productCt.children)
  .sort(function (a, b) {
    var aName = a.dataset.name,
        bName = b.dataset.name;
  
    return aName < bName? -1 : +(aName > bName);
  })
  .forEach(productCt.appendChild.bind(productCt));

reInsertProductCt();





function tempRemove(el) {
    var parent = el.parentNode,
        nextSibling = el.nextSibling;
  
    parent.removeChild(el);
  
    return function () {
        if (nextSibling) parent.insertBefore(el, nextSibling);
        else parent.appendChild(el);
    };
}
```

```html
<div id="ProductContainer"  class="row">
        <div id="1232132" data-name="B" data-category="Category_A" class="explore-cell">
         <h>TEST NAME B</h>
         <p>TEST</p>
        </div>
    <div id="123" data-name="A" data-category="Category_A" class="explore-cell">
        <h>TEST NAME A</h>
        <p>TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div id="1232152351" data-name="C" data-category="Category_A" class="explore-cell">
        <h>TEST NAME C</h>
        <p>TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div id="12342341" data-name="E" data-category="Category_B" class="explore-cell">
        <h>TEST NAME E</h>
        <p>TEST</p>
    </div>
    <div id="1325321" data-name="D" data-category="Category_B" class="explore-cell">
        <h>TEST NAME D</h>
        <p>TEST</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling only sort on them won't actually visually change the DOM, it just returns a sorted collection. So basically you just need to get the collection, sort it, then return it. Something like this should work:

```
$('#ProductContainer > div').detach().sort(function (a, b) {
  var contentA = $(a).data('name');
  var contentB = $(b).data('name');
  return (contentA < contentB) ? -1 : (contentA > contentB) ? 1 : 0;
}).appendTo('#ProductContainer');
```

You'll want to make sure that you use the detach() method and not remove(), as detach() will retain all of the data and events associated with the collection items.

Answer (score 0):

Why choose to sort by category or by name when you can sort by both?

I tried to write a generic multisort function generator, which should also work with the native array sort function.

[**JSFIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/axelduch/xbakgg4p/#base)

A function that generates the multisort, it takes two parameters.

1. The column priority list order (first by category or by name? You decide).
2. I also wanted a way to provide values for columns (since you might not retrieve them the same way for each of them), it is an object that describes for each column a function to retrieve data.

Here it is

```
function getMultisortFn(columns, provideColumnData) {
    return function (a, b) {
        for (var i = 0, l = columns.length; i < l; i++) {
            var column = columns[i];
            var aColumnData = provideColumnData[column.name](a, column.name);
            var bColumnData = provideColumnData[column.name](b, column.name);
            if (aColumnData !== bColumnData) {
                if (column.asc) {
                    return String.prototype.localeCompare.call(aColumnData, bColumnData);
                }

                return String.prototype.localeCompare.call(bColumnData, aColumnData);    
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Now this is the part where you actually use the multisort generated

```
function retrieveDataAttribute(item, attribute) {
    return $(item).data(attribute);
}

var $container = $('#ProductContainer'); 
var $products = $container.find('div');

var multisort = getMultisortFn([{
        name: 'category',
        asc: false
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        asc: true
    }], {
        name: retrieveDataAttribute,
        category: retrieveDataAttribute
    });



$products.sort(multisort);
```

And finally the DOM manipulation to apply the new order

```
$products.detach().appendTo($container);
```

**EDIT** *thanks to* [plalx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211528/plalx):

```
  $container.detach().append($products).appendTo('section.box.explore');
```

Comment: There's no need to detach the `$products` before appending them. Also, it's the `$container` you want to detach before appending the products to avoid multiple reflows.