# jquery draggable re-order after drag and drop

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I am trying to do a list of 10 iteam that are draggable, stacked from 1 to 10 from top to bottom in order.

If a user wants to drag an item at position 1 to lets say position 5. I want all the items to move up 1 position. Similary if a user moves the item from position 10 to position 7, I want item 9 to move to position 10, item 8 to position 9, item 7 to position 8 so previously positioned item 10 can take place at position 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Divs in Jquery Based on Attribute 'data-sort'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133723/sort-divs-in-jquery-based-on-attribute-data-sort)

Answer (score 0):

Check this question and answers.. You can use it after drop

[Sort Divs in Jquery Based on Attribute 'data-sort'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133723/sort-divs-in-jquery-based-on-attribute-data-sort)