# Sorting a div based on data attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright, I'm trying to make it so jQuery sorts the divs when a button is clicked,

Let's say the list looks like this,

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item" data-worth="720">Edgy</div>
  <div class="item" data-worth="420">Blaze</div>
  <div class="item" data-worth="666">Meme</div>
</div>
```

Then after the button is clicked I want it to spit out,

```
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item" data-worth="720">Edgy</div>
      <div class="item" data-worth="666">Meme</div>
      <div class="item" data-worth="420">Blaze</div>
    </div>
```

Basically sorting worth from low to high, rearanging everything and putting it back in the wrapper.

I'm honestly clueless on how I'd go on doing this, I thought of using jQuery's `.each` function but then I'd only be able to get highest value on the top, any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133723/sort-divs-in-jquery-based-on-attribute-data-sort

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh yeah just stumbled upon the thread but can't seem to find the right anwser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Divs in Jquery Based on Attribute 'data-sort'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133723/sort-divs-in-jquery-based-on-attribute-data-sort)

Comment: @Leo check comment above

Comment: What do you mean "can't find the right answer"?  The selected answer does work, and should work for you too.  Have you tried it, and it's not working for you in some way?

Comment: are you using the right selector for the sort?

Comment: Grab all data-worth's values, place them in an array- `.sort()` it, and select + prepand them based on value.

Comment: The accepted answer in the "duplicate" is overly complex and doesn't append the sorted list to the wrapper as needed in the OP's case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sort the wrapper's `divs` based on their `data('worth')`, then append the sorted list back to the wrapper:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.wrapper div').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(b).data('worth') - $(a).data('worth');
  }).appendTo('.wrapper');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Sort</button>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item" data-worth="720">Edgy</div>
  <div class="item" data-worth="420">Blaze</div>
  <div class="item" data-worth="666">Meme</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//code taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133723/sort-divs-in-jquery-based-on-attribute-data-sort

//All I have done is, presented the code such a way that it is easy for you to understand and use it in your application

function asc_sort(a, b){ return ($(b).data("worth")) > ($(a).data("worth")) ? 1 : -1; }

jQuery.fn.sortDivs = function sortDivs() {
    $(".item", this[0]).sort(asc_sort).appendTo(this[0]);
}

$('#BtnSort').on('click', function(){
    $(".wrapper").sortDivs();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="BtnSort">Sort</button>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item" data-worth="720">Edgy</div>
  <div class="item" data-worth="420">Blaze</div>
  <div class="item" data-worth="666">Meme</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item" data-worth="720">Edgy</div>
  <div class="item" data-worth="420">Blaze</div>
  <div class="item" data-worth="666">Meme</div>
</div>
<button class="clickMe">Sort</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function someFunction(){
  var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
    $wrapper.find('.item').sort(function (a, b) {
    return +b.dataset.worth - a.dataset.worth;
})
.appendTo( $wrapper );
}
$('body').on('click', '.clickMe', someFunction);
```

Here is a working: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uggkn4pc/1/)