# Sorting Data Attributes Alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

My code doesn't seem to access the data attribute name and I have tried many different codes.

```
<div class="columns offer_table_rows" style=" position:relative;" data-personal="1" data-euro="" data-vehicle="122" data-roadside="neutral false " data-national="neutral false " data-home="neutral  true" data-onward="neutral  true" data-name="Different Brand 1">
```

```js
$(".brandName").on('click', function() {
  $wrapper.find('.offer_table_rows').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).dataset('name').toLowerCase() > $(b).dataset('name').toLowerCase();
  }).appendTo($wrapper);
})

$wrapper.find('.offer_table_rows').sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.dataset.name - a.dataset.name;
})
```

When the brandName filter button is clicked the wrapper div finds a row and sorts using data attribute name. I've tried both of the above variations but none seem to access the data attribute, or I just don't know what is going wrong.

I know for sure the wrapper finds the row and it all works until the data attribute is searched, as I have number sorts that do work with the same code.

### Edit

This is not a duplicate as the proposed answer doesn't answer this question. Using `$(a).data` instead of what I have doesn't work. I am able to console.log the data names if I use 
`console.log($(a).data('name'))` but they don't seem to sort.

### Edit 2

I can console.log true false when evaluating if `data.a` is bigger than `data.b`:

```
`$(".brandName").on('click', function() { $wrapper.find('.offer_table_rows').sort(function(a, b) { // console.log(a.dataset.name >b.dataset.name); })   })
```

But if I try to make it a function that returns and appends to the wrapper it does nothing.

Comment: Use `$(a).attr('data-name')`

Comment: you can also use `$(a).data('name')`

Comment: For sorting based on data value - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133723/sort-divs-in-jquery-based-on-attribute-data-sort

Answer (score 0):

Use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

`.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));`

Comment: `a` and `b` are Element objects, not strings.

Comment: `$(".brandName").on('click', function() {
  $wrapper.find('.offer_table_rows').sort(function(a, b) {
   var x = a.dataset.name.toLowerCase();
   var y = b.dataset.name.toLowerCase();
   if (x < y) {return -1;}
   if (x > y) {return 1;}
   return 0;
    }).appendTo($wrapper);
   })`

This is a Working answer